# Local boundedness of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

According to [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) of a bounded linear operator L(v): X -> Y the bounding constant M must be the same for all elements of the preimage X of the operator. However it then says that a bounded linear operator is not a bounded function but a locally bounded function.

I thought locally bounded functions were functions bounded with a constant M(v) depending on the preimage element v, so this strikes me as contradictory. Can you clear it for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The constant $M$ such that $\Vert L x \Vert \leq M \cdot \Vert x \Vert$ holds has to be independent of $x$. But note that the right hand side nevertheless depends upon $x$ (because it is given by $M \cdot \Vert x \Vert$).

This implies that on every ball $B_r (0)$, $L$ is bounded by $M \cdot r$, because $\Vert L x \Vert \leq M \cdot \Vert x \Vert \leq M \cdot r$.

This shows that $L$ is locally bounded, because for $x \in X$ arbitrary, we have that $B_r (0)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ for $r$ large enough.

But for $L \neq 0$, you never have that $L$ is bounded in the sense that $\Vert L x \Vert \leq K$ holds for some constant $K$ and all $x \in X$, because for $x \in X$ with $L x \neq 0$ we have $\Vert L(\alpha x) \Vert = \alpha \Vert Lx\Vert \rightarrow \infty$ for $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I don't get that last part. The linearity of the operator allows ∥L(αx)∥ to be infinite, and that means that it can't be bounded by a finite M but it doesn't stops it from being locally bounded because x can be infinite, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, essentially. By linearity, the operator can not be bounded on $X$ (in the sense of $\Vert L x \Vert \leq K$ for ALL $x \in X$). But it can be bounded on the unit ball (and on any other fixed ball). The bound of $L$ on the unit ball can actually be used as $M$ in the inequality $\Vert Lx\Vert \leq M \cdot \Vert x\Vert$, because we have $\Vert L x\Vert = \Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert L(\frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}) \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert \cdot M$.